# Convert NSData byte to bit

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion, byte, bit

I have **NSMutableData** "30352514 38001300 00000001"
i need convert **byte** to **bit**
00110000001101
and that to NSString
**Thx**

Comment: What have you tried? Just asking for code is frowned up and might get your question downvoted and/or closed. Please read the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for bytes:

```
const char *byte = [data bytes];
NSLog(@"%s",byte);
```

This is for bits:

```
const char *byte = [data bytes];
unsigned int length = [data length];
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    char n = byte[i];
    char buffer[9];
    buffer[8] = 0; //for null
    int j = 8;
    while(j > 0)
    {
        if(n & 0x01)
        {
            buffer[--j] = '1';
        } else
    {
        buffer[--j] = '0';
    }
    n >>= 1;
}
printf("%s ",buffer);
```